# how to set the processing in android in background and at mean time dialogbox open and show some msg in android

Tags: android

i develop and e booking application in android ,so in this application i want to show a proceesing bar are a dialog box while system in processing mode

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask and set up the dialog in the onPreExecute method!